# Django Website Not Updating

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have created a new html file in the static/partials folder of my project and trying to see it on my Django website.  I can edit older html files in that folder and see those changes, but can not see the new html file, which is pretty annoying.  In the main urls.py, I redirect the links to pages in the static/partials folder to the base file, which is redirected to a js file to retrieve template information.

This is what the js file looks like that redirects links to the partials html pages (the essential parts):

```
x = angular.module('x', []);

.
.
.

x.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when(
        '/', {templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html'}).
      when(
        '/newpage',
        {
          templateUrl: '/static/partials/newpage.html',
          controller: "ControllerName"
        });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Depending on how your site is set up, you may have to run `python manage.py collectstatic` to see the updates.

Comment: yes, I've done a while ago that but it did not change anything yet.

Comment: If you go to 127.0.0.1:8000/static/partials/newpage.html in your browser, do you see anything?

Comment: So another part of the problem is that I can't check it out locally due to a "no module named" error in GitBash and a "django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user" error in CommandLine.  Basically, the site that I am using is a test site since no one visits it (and eventually will be moved onto a new server).